# Mocha test are not running in right order using before/beforeEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I use the following code and in the before I copy files that the tests after are using assertion but when I run it the **before/each** is happen after the test, what am I missing here?

I tried also with beforeach without success

```
describe(" Handler", function()  {

    before((done) => {

        fs.stat(utils.pathSetup() + "/ins/", function (err, stats) {
            if (!err) {
                console.log("success");
            } else {
                let lclpath = utils.pathSetup();
                Loder.add({folderPath: lclpath + "/test/testcontent/ins"});
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
        done();
    });
```

**//This are called before the previous statement why????????**
  //This should happen after the before has finished,they are in the same test block and this called is right after...

```
  Handler.invoke(req, res)
        .then((Ref) => {

        }).done();

    ee.on('Started', (arg) => {
        evtResStart = arg;
    });
```

in debug when I put BP it stops in before and click on step into take me to the Handler.invoke instead of inside the before...:(

Any idea what could be the reason for such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `done` in your tests/befores, you need to call `done()` inside your callbacks, e.g.

```
before((done) => {
    fs.stat(utils.pathSetup() + "/ins/", function (err, stats) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("success");
        } else {
            let lclpath = utils.pathSetup();
            Loder.add({folderPath: lclpath + "/test/testcontent/ins"});
            console.log(err);
        }
        done();
    });
});
```

Edit: Assuming the comments in your question are supposed to be formatted as code, is your `Handler` stuff in at `it` block?

```
it('should do something', () => {
    Handler.invoke(req, res)
        .then((Ref) => {

        }).done();

    ee.on('Started', (arg) => {
        evtResStart = arg;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks :) , I try it and its not working :( any other idea ?

Comment: Just to hop on this: `fs.statSync()` should also solve the issue as there is not really a need to run this asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting `done();` inside the callback of [fs.stat](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_stat_path_callback)?
In this way your tests should run as you want

```
before((done) => {

    fs.stat(utils.pathSetup() + "/ins/", function (err, stats) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("success");
        } else {
            let lclpath = utils.pathSetup();
            Loder.add({folderPath: lclpath + "/test/testcontent/ins"});
            console.log(err);
        }
        done();
    });
});
```